# Rails, ActiveRecord, Finding all events that fall on weekend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, find, where-clause

I was Wondering if someone could help with this ActiveRecord query. I have Events that have a start and end date. I wanted to run a cron job that gets all events every Thursday that fall on the coming weekend.

Something like...

```
@events = Event.where("start_date <= ?", (Date.today + 3.days)).where("end_date >= ?", (Date.today + 3.days))
```

I know the above is incorrect, but hoping someone can perhaps enlighten me on an easier way to find the events for this query... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I try to translate your question to an algorithm I think that what you are after is this: find all events which have the `start_date` *during or before* the coming weekend (i.e. before the weekend ends) *and* the `end_date` *during or after* the coming weekend (i.e. after the weekend starts). That way we'll **find events that cover, at least partially, the weekend days**.

If you run your rake on Thursdays, then the next weekend can be retrieved as this:

```
weekend_start = Date.today.end_of_week - 1    # the Saturday's date
weekend_end   = Date.today.end_of_week        # the Sunday's date
```

With this, the query is easy:

```
@events = Event.where("start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", weekend_end, weekend_start)
```

If your `start_date` and `end_date` columns were not DATE but DATETIME columns, you would have to define the start and end of weekend like the following instead:

```
weekend_start = Time.zone.now.end_of_week.midnight - 1.day   # 00:00 at Saturday
weekend_end   = Time.zone.now.end_of_week                    # 23:59 at Sunday
```

The definitions are using `Time.zone` to calculate the times in the local time zone.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's suggestion! For simplicity and ease of comprehension, I used @BoraMa solution. Clear and gets the right query! Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

We can find `start time` and `end time` of next weekends, so the query will be easy after that.

```
# Start weekends time
start_next_saturday = Date.today.end_of_week.at_beginning_of_day - 1.days
# End weekends time
end_next_sunday     = Date.today.end_of_week.at_end_of_day

arel_table = Event.arel_table
@events    = Event.where(arel_table[:start_date].lteq(end_next_sunday)
                          .and(arel_table[:end_date].gteq(start_next_saturday)))
```

Btw, `Date.today + 3.days` maybe an incorrect approach, so find the weekends time with above logic is more accurate!

Comment: This finds the events on *last* weekend whereas the OP wants the *coming* weekend. And why AREL?

Comment: Ah ha, thanks for suggestion, just an option to make query

Comment: Thanks HieuPham ! Your solution is viable, but used BoraMa due to simplicity. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Event.where(created_at: (Date.today.end_of_week-1..Date.today.end_of_week))
```